# Is there a risk of having xmlrpc.php on my site?

Tags: 7, security

I recently noticed that all of my sites have the file `xmlrpc.php`.

Searching it led me to "[Gain Control of WordPress by Exploiting XML-RPC](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/gain-control-wordpress-by-exploiting-xml-rpc-0174864/)", and also to "[Drupal Core - Critical - Multiple Vulnerabilities - SA-CORE-2016-001](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2016-001)".

I'm running Drupal 7.56.

Does this file pose a threat whatsoever to my site?
Should I just delete it to be safe?

If I should keep it, what added benefit does it give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are save.** At least to what we know now.

The first linked article is wordpress related. This is totally different code. Not drupal related at all!

> Drupal had a known security flaw in versions lower than 6.38 / 7.43 /
>   8.04

So your version 7.56 is patched. Always make sure to update to the latest version and you're good.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! While I am inclined to agree, it does seem like the file can lead to a vulnerability. In regards to the original vulnerability via the 2016 SA Core: "This vulnerability is mitigated by the fact that you must have enabled a module that provides an XML-RPC method that is vulnerable to brute-forcing."
If I enable a module that, unknown to my knowledge, utilizes this file, I'll be putting myself at risk, no? Apologies in advance if I'm misunderstanding anything. :)

Comment: You're putting yourself at the same risk every time you use any bit of software @Brian, they all have potential security holes. For this one specifically, the brute-force vulnerability was patched so assuming you have a version later than that, you're fine, unless a new vulnerability is discovered. Hopefully it won't be, but there's always the chance there will be. Same could be said about index.php, which serves most of Drupal (google "Drupalgeddon" for a fun story if you're not already familiar with the term). If the risk is unacceptable to you, delete the file :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Clive! As it turns out, I believe I was misreading the SA Core; as it read "This vulnerability is mitigated by ... vulnerable to brute-forcing," I was under the impression that that was Drupal's fix.
Going to the official changelog for the newest version cleared that up for me, along with your answer!
Thanks again. :)

Comment: Oh and just to clarify, the mitigating factor applies to installs of Drupal that _don't_ have the patch. They're basically saying "there's a nasty security vulnerability in v7.43, but even in 7.43 you have to have certain types of module enabled, otherwise the vulnerability isn't exploitable. Once you upgrade to 7.44+, the vulnerability won't be there for anyone"

Comment: You caught me right in the middle of trying to explain just that ;)